# WP7 LongListSelector properties not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the LongListSelector from the Mango Silverlight toolkit.
But I need to be able to set 'MaximumFlickVelocity' and 'BufferSize' but neither do anything.

For example:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector IsFlatList="True" MaximumFlickVelocity="10" BufferSize="5"  IsBouncy="False">
```

The properties there have no effect at all, except 'IsFlatList'.

Thanks.

EDIT: I just noticed in the documentation that all the properties I need at marked as Obsolete. So could anyone tell me what alternatives I have? Because the performance on this isn't great at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of list you have. If you can afford to load more items into the list, as the user scrolls to the bottom of the list, you can use the `StretchingBottom` event on the longlistselector.
The property `IsBouncy` defaults to true in the latest release, so `StretchingBottom` is fired everytime the user scrolls to the bottom and then some.

In essence, you can play with the events and the `ItemsSource` property to improve the performance in an extremely long list. Well, I am not sure if it will be of much help, but it`s worth a try.

Good luck.